# VBA: Cell designations not being evaluated

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code in VB:

ActiveCell.Formula = " = COMPANYNAME " & " & " & "R[-12]C[-3]" & " & " & "VLOOKUP(RC[-6],R3C7:R22C18,9)"

I want to get a cell that has in it: = COMPANYNAME & D25 & VLOOKUP(A26,$G$3:$R$22,9)

Instead, I get a cell with  = COMPANYNAME & R[-12]C[-3] & VLOOKUP(RC[-6],R3C7:R22C18,9)"

Basically, the cell designations are not being evaluated.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Change ActiveCell.Formula to ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1

By using ".Formula", it expects cells to be referenced in "A1" fashion, and therefore doesn't know how to compute the R/C references, and appears to see the whole thing as just a string instead of a formula (also you may need to remove the spaces from between the &'s).

Comment: That did it.  Thanks!